# Angular ngrx test with jest throw error ` console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29`

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-test, ngrx-store-8.0

I do the testing for my `ngrx/store` with `jestjs`. i got the testing passing result. eventhough getting an error like:

```
console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden
        at dispatchError (C:\722333\USD\Project\AOS.UI\NG-USD\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:60:19)
        at Object.validCORSHeaders (C:\722333\USD\Project\AOS.UI\NG-USD\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:72:5)
        at receiveResponse (C:\722333\USD\Project\AOS.UI\NG-USD\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:842:21)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\722333\USD\Project\AOS.UI\NG-USD\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:677:38)
        at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)
        at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\722333\USD\Project\AOS.UI\NG-USD\node_modules\request\request.js:1066:10)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:13)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:575:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:17)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:449:22) undefined
```

Any one help me to understand this above issue? and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
as per Luctia suggession i fixed the cors issue. but getting an error like:

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)
```

need to add any workaround for this?

Comment: It appears you have an asynchronous test. You need either use a `fakeAsync` with `tick` to make the time "pass" or provide `done: DoneFn` as a callback in `it` and call `done()` when it's done or `done.fail()` if it's fail

Comment: @Sergey - how to call done function? any help? Here is my test code : https://jsfiddle.net/L2yjw5kp/

Comment: Are you sure that you are debugging the right test? It appears that error is not about the test you've shown, because such kind of errors usually appear in tests which have `.subscribe` or any async functionality (setTimeout, promise.then() and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using the store and effects for the test. I'm going to assume the effect will make an http request, causing this issue.

That's why I would encourage to mock the service:

```
{
  provide: GoogleBooksService,
  useValue: { searchBooks: jest.fn() },
}
```

See the [NgRx Example App](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/effects/book.effects.spec.ts#L25-L28) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your browser is blocking Cross-origin Read (CORB). Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@siddhartha.ng/disable-cross-origin-on-chrome-for-localhost-c644b131db19) article. Hope that helps!

Comment: agree, I fixed the cors issue, getting another error.. can you suggest any solution for this?